# ArcMap toolbox script with draw geometries parameter

Tags: arcmap, arcpy, arcgis-10.1, geometry, parameters

I have an arcpy script in toolbox, that need one additional parameter to draw geometry(ies) which will work as a filter. I have done something similar using arcobjects using GPFeatureRecordSetLayerClass as an input parameter and creating temporary layer. If feature set exist, then ArcMap allow to draw geometries in it. Something similar is done if default ArcMap tools "Server Tools>Data Extraction>Extract Data" where feature set "schema" parameter have a dynamic value [toolbox folder path][shapefile] that look something like this

```
C:\Users\... ...\Desktop10.1\ArcToolbox\My Toolboxes\aoi.shp
```

When I tried to insert scheme path manually, it tells me that files does not exist. Any ideas to how to replicate feature set behavior from the default "Extract Data" tool?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this using Python with ArcPy and Feature Sets as per the examples in the **[Working with feature sets and record sets](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//002z0000001n000000)** page in the Online Help.  If you have already tried this, then perhaps you can edit your question to make what you have done and where you are stuck clearer.